# I am using SugarCRM Version 6.5.17, I want to add a custom autoincrement field in the opportunity. How is that possible?

Tags: custom-controls, auto-increment, sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM Version 6.5.17, I want to make an auto-increment field in the opportunity module. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are unfortunately no ways to accomplish this through Studio at time of writing. There are also no officially documented articles I can find immediately on Sugar's site. However, there are plenty of posts on doing so using code on the Sugar community if you search for them. They have used this metadata in certain places, such as [Trackers](https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev/blob/6f893460acedc6935ae14f14cb0048bb679ccb7f/modules/Trackers/vardefs.php)  (specifically the id field). You can utilise this logic through the extension framework by placing this code in a file (name doesn't matter) at the following location:

custom/Extension/modules/Opportunities/Ext/Vardefs/your_filename.php

```
<?php
$dictionary['Opportunity']['fields']['your_autoincrement_field'] = array (
    'required' => true,
    'name' => 'your_autoincrement_field',
    'vname' => 'LBL_YOUR_AUTOINCREMENT_FIELD',
    'type' => 'int',
    'massupdate' => 0,
    'comments' => 'Automatically generated number field',
    'help' => 'User friendly description of field',
    'importable' => 'true',
    'duplicate_merge' => 'disabled',
    'duplicate_merge_dom_value' => '0',
    'audited' => false,
    'reportable' => true,
    'calculated' => false,
    'auto_increment'=> true,
);
$dictionary['Opportunity']['indices']['your_autoincrement_field'] = array(
    'name' => 'your_autoincrement_field',
    'type' => 'unique',
    'fields' => array(
        'your_autoincrement_field'
    ),
);
?>
```

Feel free to replace"your_autoincrement_field" with whatever name you want for it.

After that, go to Admin>Repair>Quick Repair and Rebuild. Once that's done, the field should be visible and available to place on layouts.